# MySQL installer seems to be stalled?

Tags: installation, mysql, download

I downloaded MySQL installer. I chose the Developer Default Setup Type. Now it's downloading the various components of MySQL. There is an issue here: the downloading seems to be stalled. As you can see, some components have already completed downloaded, but others are still downloading. It had been downloading for over an hour now and the percentages have not changed. There has been no visible progress so far after this state. What could be the cause of this? How can I make sure that the installer is really working instead of stalling? It seems that the installer downloaded some components and ... stopped working? I have a wireless internet connection. I don't know whether this could be the issue.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I got bored waiting and I just canceled the install. It turned out that the installer was stalled. Then I started the installer again. I selected the Developer Default Setup Type again, and I repeated everything as I did it the first time. The second time the installer ran much faster. Now when it came to the Installation step, all the products or components of MySQL which had been already downloaded did not need to be downloaded again. They just were installed. The products which were incompletely downloaded the first time had to be downloaded again the second time, but the downloading was much faster.

If MySQL installer shows no progress during this step, it is better to just cancel it, and then restart it again. The next time it should work as expected.